# Directory Permission Problems When I Deploy PHP Script on Openshift

Tags: php, git, zip, openshift

I am deploy a cf image host 1.6.5 on Openshift using Git. Some of the directories do not have write permission when I running installer script.

The cf image host 1.6.1 installer script will generate a setting file in a directory called "inc".

I have done `git push` for the zip file of cf image host 1.6.5(says cf_image_1.6.5.zip) onto Openshift using git,and unziped this file to app-root/repo/php directory. The installer script can run okay. If I unzip file at local machine, `git add` and `git commit` and `git push`,the setting file can not be generated in the directory inc. If I manually change permission to 777, it is okay.
But I check the file using `ls -la`, both two methods' the owner is myself.

How do I deploy the process work when `git push`? Which user of the remote machine is deploying these scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along this (adjust permissions)

```
git update-index --chmod=+w -- $(git ls-files folder/with/wrong/permissions/*)
```

and add, commit and push.

Deploy should happen under your default openshift user. (See uder Webinterface->App: Userpart of the ssh-git url displayed there.

Comment: thanks a lot,I have find root cause,default user does not have write permissions on some directories,I add write permission with "chmod +w" and git commit &&push,it works.